# Installing Coverage.py - No matching distribution found

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

I'm working on a Django project and want to set up [Coverage](https://realpython.com/testing-in-django-part-1-best-practices-and-examples/) on my project.

```
$ pip install coverage

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coverage (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for coverage
```

Does this error mean the package is no longer supported? Just wondering what I should try to get this installed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the SSL certificate. I upgrade to a newer version of pip.